# I want to provide dynamic values to the paramaters of Citrus annotation(@CitrusXmlTest)

Tags: java, annotations, citrus-framework

The values I want to provide dynamically  is TestCase Name  and Package name. How can I do this. If I am providing values through variable then it is giving the following error "The value for annotation attribute CitrusXmlTest.name must be a constant". Now I am giving like this

```
@CitrusXmlTest(name="Test",packageName="file:D://xitrus//myFirstTest.xml")
```

I want above statement to be

```
@CitrusXmlTest(name=variable name,packageName=variable name)
```

or in some other way to insert values dynamically  please help me...

[pom image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRiw0.png),[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRZkv.png),[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27nhW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is against Java annotation specification and is not possible due to these language limitations. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

In case you need to load test cases in a dynamic way you can use packageScan option in `@CitrusXmlTest` annotation:

```
@CitrusXmlTest(packageScan = "com.something.foo")
public void citrusPackageScanIT() {}
```

This will load and execute all XML test case definitions in package `com.something.foo`. The XML test definitions are free to use different test names then.

If you want to pass some dynamic data to your test case you should use a TestNG data provider (example given here: https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-dataprovider).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Instead of providing package can we provide path out project ie can we give value to the package scan like this

Comment: packageScan="file:D:\\xitrus\\myFirstTest\\xml\\")

Comment: No, loading files from external file resource is not possible. Files must be part of the project classpath

Comment: If we give packageName like this                                                                                 

 packageName="file:D:\\xitrus\\myFirstTest\\xml\\"                                
                                                                                                                     then Citrus is going in to that folder and executing only nameOftheTest.xml                                                                                   
  is there any way to execute other xml's with in the given folder path other than given test name with xml.

Comment: Honestly I did not know that the packageName can also be used with an external file path. Citrus surprised me here after all these years. I tried to also use this external file path in packageScan option, but that did not work. So executing multiple files coming from external folder is not possible at the moment. As mentioned before you can use packageScan option but the test files need to be part of the project classpath sources then.

Comment: when declaring global variables in  Citrus-context.xml can we make global variables as final.

Comment: getting a bit out of scope for the initial question but global variables are final by definition. you can only overwrite the global variable value within one test scope. it is not possible to override a global variable so other tests see the value update, too.

Comment: I am using a test name variable "Hello"  In System.setProperty("citrus.test.name.variable", "Hello"); In citrus context I giving value to it  but when citrus is executing the test method it overriding value of variable "Hello" with the test name. I don't want citrus to override that test name variable.

Comment: Hello christoph as we discussed earlier you said that only packgeName is executing xml files outside of the project but  packgeScan  also   executing the xml files from out side of the project. but only pom.xml file specified correctly I don't know which configuration in pom.xml is helping packageScan to execute xml files outside of the project. could you help me to figure it out.

Comment: you can find pom images in the question